# No puedo alinear correctamente los divs

Tags: html, css, div

necesito ayuda al alinear un div, tengo 2 divs intento alinearlos **verticalmente** y no quedan: en los divs quiero poner una imagen de una persona en primer plano, y una frace que aya dicho al lado de la imagen **(La imagen a la izquierda y el texto a la derecha)** le agrege la decoracion de la esquina doblada como una hoja de papel y le agrege una sombra muy leve que apenas se nota, ahora quiero que los dos divs esten **separados y centrados** de todos los lados de forma de que quede todo simetrico
**(Pongan en patalla completa el codigo para verlo)**

**Codigo:**

```css
    .toping{
     width: 100%;
    }
    .presentation {
     float: left;
    -webkit-box-shadow: 4px 6px 52px -9px rgba(0,0,0,0.34);
    -moz-box-shadow: 4px 6px 52px -9px rgba(0,0,0,0.34);
     box-shadow: 4px 6px 52px -9px rgba(0,0,0,0.34);
       background: none repeat scroll 0 0 #97C02F; /* color de fondo */
           color: #FFFFFF; /* color de texto */
                    margin: 2em auto;
                    overflow: hidden;
                    padding: 1em 1.5em;
                    position: relative;
                    width: 480px; /* ancho */
    }
             .presentation:before {
                    background: none repeat scroll 0 0 #658E15; /* color esquina */
                     border-color: #FFFFFF #FFFFFF #658E15 #658E15; /* color de borde */
                    border-style: solid;
                   border-width: 0 16px 16px 0;
                    content: "";
                    display: block;
                    position: absolute;
         right: 0;
          top: 0;
         width: 0;
    }
    .presentation2 {
     float: left;
     -webkit-box-shadow: 4px 6px 52px -9px rgba(0,0,0,0.34);
     -moz-box-shadow: 4px 6px 52px -9px rgba(0,0,0,0.34);
     box-shadow: 4px 6px 52px -9px rgba(0,0,0,0.34);
       background: none repeat scroll 0 0 #97C02F; /* color de fondo */
           color: #FFFFFF; /* color de texto */
                    margin: 2em auto;
                    overflow: hidden;
                    padding: 1em 1.5em;
                    position: relative;
                    width: 480px; /* ancho */
    }
             .presentation2:before {
                    background: none repeat scroll 0 0 #658E15; /* color esquina */
                     border-color: #FFFFFF #FFFFFF #658E15 #658E15; /* color de borde */
                    border-style: solid;
                   border-width: 0 16px 16px 0;
                    content: "";
                    display: block;
                    position: absolute;
         right: 0;
          top: 0;
         width: 0;
    }
```

```html
  <div class="toping">
   <div class="presentation">
    <span>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit, sed do eiusmod
    tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam,
    quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo
    consequat. Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse
    cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non
    proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum.</span>    
   </div>
   <div class="presentation2">
    <span>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit, sed do eiusmod
    tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam,
    quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo
    consequat. Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse
    cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non
    proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum.</span>    
   </div>
```

Comment: Déjame ver si entendí, quieres que estén centrados ambos divs tanto vertical como horizontalmente?

Comment: @BenderPaisa correctamente

Answer (score 0):

Lo que se me ocurre es meter los dos `div` dentro de otro `div`, luego utilizar el `display: flex` en el `div.toping` para centrar el `div` creado que contiene las dos tarjetas, con esto se centrarán siempre en relación al `div.toping`.

Revisalo en pantalla completa.

```css
.toping{
  width: 100%;
  display: flex;
}

.content{
  margin: auto;
}

.presentation {
  float: left;
  -webkit-box-shadow: 4px 6px 52px -9px rgba(0,0,0,0.34);
  -moz-box-shadow: 4px 6px 52px -9px rgba(0,0,0,0.34);
  box-shadow: 4px 6px 52px -9px rgba(0,0,0,0.34);
  background: none repeat scroll 0 0 #97C02F; /* color de fondo */
  color: #FFFFFF; /* color de texto */
  margin: 2em auto;
  overflow: hidden;
  padding: 1em 1.5em;
  position: relative;
  width: 480px; /* ancho */
}

.presentation:before {
  background: none repeat scroll 0 0 #658E15; /* color esquina */
  border-color: #FFFFFF #FFFFFF #658E15 #658E15; /* color de borde */
  border-style: solid;
  border-width: 0 16px 16px 0;
  content: "";
  display: block;
  position: absolute;
  right: 0;
  top: 0;
  width: 0;
}

.presentation2 {
  float: left;
  -webkit-box-shadow: 4px 6px 52px -9px rgba(0,0,0,0.34);
  -moz-box-shadow: 4px 6px 52px -9px rgba(0,0,0,0.34);
  box-shadow: 4px 6px 52px -9px rgba(0,0,0,0.34);
  background: none repeat scroll 0 0 #97C02F; /* color de fondo */
  color: #FFFFFF; /* color de texto */
  margin: 2em auto;
  overflow: hidden;
  padding: 1em 1.5em;
  position: relative;
  width: 480px; /* ancho */
}

.presentation2:before {
  background: none repeat scroll 0 0 #658E15; /* color esquina */
  border-color: #FFFFFF #FFFFFF #658E15 #658E15; /* color de borde */
  border-style: solid;
  border-width: 0 16px 16px 0;
  content: "";
  display: block;
  position: absolute;
  right: 0;
  top: 0;
  width: 0;
}
```

```html
<div class="toping">
  <div class="content">
    <div class="presentation">
      <span>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit, sed do eiusmod
      tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam,
      quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo
      consequat. Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse
      cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non
      proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum.</span>    
    </div>
    <div class="presentation2">
      <span>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit, sed do eiusmod
      tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam,
      quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo
      consequat. Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse
      cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non
      proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum.</span>    
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Y como puedo dejar un espacio entre esos dos divs?

Comment: @BrianMartinez pues aplica un margin a alguno de los dos